# "Uncaught TypeError: Object(...) is not a function" error on Vue 2.6.12

Tags: vue.js, vcalendar

My situation: IE11 support required.

Current version in my project

- Vue : 2.6.12 (Requirement version from my client cuz Vue3.x doesn't
  support ie11 perfectly)
- v-calendar : 3.0.0-alpha.4
- babel-polyfill :6.26.0

It occurs this error

> Module parse failed: Unexpected token (5222:58)

on console, so I tried to change the `webpack.base.conf` as below:

```
{
  test: /\.js$/,
  loader: 'babel-loader',
  include: [resolve('src'), resolve('test'), resolve('node_modules/webpack-dev-server/client'), resolve('node_modules/v-calendar')]
},
```

and then I got this error

> Uncaught TypeError: Object(...) is not a function

on Chrome dev tool and

> export 'h' was not found in 'vue'

on console ....(eslint message)

What should I do about it?

Comment: Hard to say without knowing the content of your own js files. As a shot in the dark, I'd comment out all but one `resolve(...)` item in your `include` array and comment in one after another until you'll get your error message so that you know where to look.

Comment: Does removing `resolve('node_modules/v-calendar')` fix the issue? I have the same `include` statement except I pass in `vuex-cache` instead of `v-calendar` and do not have any issues. Make sure `node_modules/v-calendar` exists. If it does not, make sure its in your package.json and run `npm install`